# Rails 4 to_xml issue with accessor overwriting in model

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, export-to-xml

I have a problem with overwriting accessors in a model and using the `to_xml` method later on the model. The problem is, that `to_xml` seems to use the default getter method, rather than using `read_attribute`.

My model:

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def created_at
    date = self[:created_at]
    "#{german_date(date)} #{german_time(date)} #{I18n.t(:clock)}"
  end

  ...
end
```

I'm using this, in order to easily run through parameters in my haml views, by always having the correct method for labels and text_fields. Because I need some attributes to be shown modified, I've overwritten the accessor.

```
-# Minified example ...
= form_for ...
  - %i(a b c d e).each do |attr|
    = f.label attr
    = f.text_field attr
```

The problem is: When I run `to_xml`, I get this problem:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `xmlschema' for "15.03.2009 18:17 Uhr":String
```

Obviously, `to_xml` is using my custom getter rather than `read_attribute(:created_at)`, which would give the correct value. I'm astonished to not have found this problem somewhere else, but IS there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way using the options and a block with `to_xml`

```
announcment.to_xml(except: :created_at, procs: -> (options, record) {
  options[:builder].tag!("created-at", record.read_attribute(:created_at))
})
```

That's not pretty though. I would just use a decorator for your views and leave the model attribute methods alone, Draper works great with Rails 4.

Comment: I'm accepting it because of the tip with Draper. It seems to be a great gem! The first 'solution' though is far too cumbersome.